# How to update values of php form and database with a button?

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-update

So, i've a php form, i added a button to load this same form but there i want to update all the fields separately, so i change `<td><?php echo $donnees['prenom'] ?></td>` into  `<input type="hidden" value="<? echo $donnees['prenom']?>" name="prenom" />` but it doesn't display anything.. and i don't know where to write my query. 
Here's my form :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Formulaire Freelance</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #fff;overflow-x:scroll;"> 

    <?php
        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['autoriser'] != '1'){
            header("location:connexion.php");
        }
    ?>


        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top " role="navigation">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand menuCentre" href="deconnexion.php">Se d&eacute;connecter</a>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <form method="post" action="modification-freelance.php">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Modifier" name="valider" />
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableau">
            <thead>
                <tr class="danger">
                    <td>Pr&eacute;nom</td>
                    <td>Nom</td>
                    <td>Adresse</td>
                    <td>Code postal</td>
                    <td>Ville</td>
                    <td>T&eacute;l&eacute;phone</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Tarif journalier</td>
                    <td>Apparaitre sur le site ?</td>
                    <td>Pr&eacute;sentation</td>
                    <td>M&eacute;tier principal</td>
                    <td>Autres m&eacute;tier</td>
                    <td>Comp&eacute;tences</td>
                    <td>Lien de la photo</td>
                    <td>Lien du C.V</td>
                    <!--<td>Lien du R.I.B.</td>-->
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-center">Projet</td>
                    <td>Commentaires</td>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <?php
        include "AccessBddMysqli.php";
        $reponse = mysql_query("SELECT i.*, m.*, p.* FROM infofreelance i 
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN metier m ON m.id = i.idMetier 
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN projet p ON p.id = i.idProjet"
                                ) or die(mysql_error());
        while($donnees = mysql_fetch_array($reponse) ){
        /* Vérification = si il y a des fichier upload ou non.*/
                $cheminProjet = "fichier/projet/".$donnees['fichier'];
                $cheminCv = "fichier/cv/".$donnees['lienCv'];
                $cheminRib = "fichier/rib/".$donnees['lienRib'];
                $cheminPhoto = "fichier/photo/".$donnees['lienPhoto'];


            // si 0 sÃƒÂ©lectionner alors non sinon oui
            if($donnees['apparaitreSite'] == 0)
                $donnees['apparaitreSite'] = "non";
            else
                $donnees['apparaitreSite'] = "oui";

    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['prenom'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['nom']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['adresse']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['codePostal']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['ville']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['telephone']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['email']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['tarifJournalier']?> &euro;</td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['apparaitreSite']?></td>
                    <td style="width:25em;">
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="15" class="form-control">
                            <?php echo $donnees['presentation']?>
                        </textarea><br/></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['libelle']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['autreMetier']?></td>
                    <td style="width:25em;">
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="10" class="form-control">
                            <?php echo $donnees['idCompetence']?>
                        </textarea><br/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?
                        if($cheminPhoto != "fichier/photo/"){
                    ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $cheminPhoto ?>" class="btn btn-success" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span></a><br/><br/>
                            <img src="<?php echo $cheminPhoto ?>" width="50" alt="">
                    <?
                        }
                    ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?
                        if($cheminCv != "fichier/cv/"){
                    ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $cheminCv ?>"class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span></a>
                    <?
                        }
                    ?>
                    </td>
                    <!--
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        //if($cheminRib == "fichier/rib/"){
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php //echo $cheminRib ?>"class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></a>
                        <?php
                        //}
                        //else?>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign">

                    </td>
                    -->
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['description'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                    <?
                        if($donnees['lien'] != ""){
                    ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $donnees['lien'] ?>"class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span></a>  
                    <?
                        }
                    ?>                  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?
                        if($cheminProjet != "fichier/projet/"){
                    ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $cheminProjet ?>"class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span></a>  
                    <?
                        }
                    ?>                  
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:25em;">
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="15" class="form-control">
                            <?php echo $donnees['commentaire']?>
                        </textarea><br/>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                </tbody>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
```

What should i do?
    Sorry for my English

Comment: Well, when the page loads, i will get the data from the table & display in the form. I am just curious whats the purpose of that button ??

Comment: It's to reach the second form.. the one I want to be able to change the datas..

Comment: you mean a different form in a different page ?

Comment: The same form in a different page.. The first to consult and te second to update..

Comment: if, its the same inputs ? why you want two page, you cam make it as one page. is there any specific reason you want it in two page ?

Comment: There is no specific reason, but i thought it was a good idea.. my kwoledge in sql and php is weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting a session variable when you click on update button like this

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$_SESSION['update']="yes";
}
```

get values from database before form like this

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","dbname");
$sql = "select * from table";
$rs = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
```

then have form like this

```
<form method="post" >
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['update'])){   echo $row['name']; } ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['update'])){   echo $row['age']; } ?>"/>
</form>
```

also when you leave this page or do any other function dont forget to unset the session like this

```
unset($_SESSION['update']);
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: donnees in D:\wamp\www\projet\freelance\modification-freelance.php on line 35     Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\wamp\www\projet\freelance\modification-freelance.php on line         Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\wamp\www\projet\freelance\modification-freelance.php on line 99     Fatal error: Call to undefined function VALUES() in D:\wamp\www\projet\freelance\modification-freelance.php on line 100     I have some errors..

Comment: line 35 : <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableau"> and line 99-100 : VALUES('{$donnees}');   }

Comment: i think `$donnees` is the array you use to get values from database.Since you are declaring it in while condition it has scope inside the while loop.You might probably try to get it outside while loop

Comment: It works, the datas display correctly! In one page which is better than my first idea! Thank you!